# .net update changed values before download page as Word file

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page that I fill the values dynamically with jquery. I want to generate a Word file after this, but when the Word file is generated it is not getting the new values that jquery brought.

Aspx.code

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:Label runat="server" id="name_cont">@Contract@</asp:Label>
<asp:Button OnClick="generateWord" id="botao" Text="Generate Word" runat="server" />
</form>

void generateWord(Object sender , EventArgs e)
{
     response.ContentType = "application/msword";   
     response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=notification.doc");
     response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";

}
```

Jquery code:

```
...
$("#name_cont").text(newValue);
...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your asp:Button is making a full post back to the server.  The code-behind is then setting the ContentType to application/msword which means that what is returned is a MS Word document that cannot be accessed through jQuery.

Comment: I would recommend getting all the data to your backend so that your document can be generated there.  Otherwise you can use the Javascript API for office to do everything clientside. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160953(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I didn't find example or tutorial of how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Because your label is `runat="server"` the id may not be what you think. Try

```
$('#<%=name_cont.ClientID  %>').text(newValue);
```

for your query. This will populate the query with server generated id of `name_cont`.

Note: your javascript will need to be generated in your page, not in a separate js file, which isn't necessarily a good practice.

Comment: The value is changed with jquery before I click in the button to generate wordfile, regardless runat=server, but when I call the generateWord Function the values are not loaded to the word file. I put the js code inside the page but it is still the same thing